# Displaying the content of Subnet in a form of table in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, azure-powershell

I am trying to display the PowerShell data in the following format.

```
Vnet        Subnet
----        ------
AZRWUSVNET1 default
Corpvnet    MgmtSubnet 
Corpvnet    Devsubnet
Corpvnet    QASubnet 
Corpvnet    ProdSubnet
```

I have tried this below script

```
$a = Get-AzVirtualNetwork
$b = $a | Select-Object Name,Subnets
$ResourceList = @()
foreach ($item in $b)
{
  $vnetname = ($b | Where-Object -Property Name -EQ ($item.Name))
  $subnet = $vnetname.Subnets.Name
  $vnetname = $item.Name
  $VMObject = New-Object PSObject
  $VMObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Vnet" -Value $vnetname
  $VMObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Subnet" -Value $subnet
  $ResourceList += $VMObject
}
$ResourceList
```

But I am getting the data in the following format

```
Vnet        Subnet
----        ------
AZRWUSVNET1 default
Corpvnet    {MgmtSubnet, Devsubnet, QASubnet, ProdSubnet…}
```

Can anyone please help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just tried this and it resolved

```
$vNets = Get-AzVirtualNetwork | Select-Object Name, Subnets
$ResourceList=@()

foreach($vNet in $vNets){
  foreach($subnet in $vNet.Subnets){
    #$subnatename=$vnet.subnets.Name
    $VMObject = New-Object PSObject
    $VMObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Vnet" -Value $vNet.Name
    $VMObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Subnet" -Value $subnet.Name
    $ResourceList += $VMObject
  }
}

$ResourceList
```

Only change is $subnet.Name

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code significantly by using `Select-Object` to extract and annotate the `Subnets` values:

```
Get-AzVirtualNetwork |Select-Object -Property @{Name='Vnet';E=
Name'} -ExpandProperty Subnets |Select-Object Vnet,@{Name='Subnet';Expression={$_.Name}}
```

---

If you insist on using loops, you'll need a *nested loop* (since the individual subnets are nested inside each vnet):

```
$vNets = Get-AzVirtualNetwork | Select-Object Name, Subnets
$ResourceList=@()

foreach($vNet in $vNets){
  foreach($subnet in $vNet.Subnets){
    $VMObject = New-Object PSObject
    $VMObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Vnet" -Value $vNet.Name
    $VMObject | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Subnet" -Value $subnet.Name
    $ResourceList += $VMObject
  }
}

$ResourceList
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution...I ran both the solution in the first one I was getting this error The property cannot be processed because the property "Name" already exists. And in the solution with nested For loop here is what I am getting

Comment: Vnet        Subnet
----        ------
AZRWUSVNET1 Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSSubnet
Corpvnet    Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSSubnet
Corpvnet    Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSSubnet
Corpvnet    Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSSubnet
Corpvnet    Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSSubnet
Corpvnet    Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Network.Models.PSSubnet

Comment: @askwizard I didn't have an Azure tenant to test against, so I assumed `Subnets` was  a flat list of strings. Updated the answer